# serialize foreign key in django rest

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get reviews belonging to specific product.So Suppose i am accessing data from api as

```
api/userreview/productname
```

using this view

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def product_userreview(request,productname):

try:
    snippets = product_review.objects.filter(product_id__slug = productname)
except snippets.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = productReviewSerializer(snippets)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this class

```
class product_review(models.Model):
  product=models.ForeignKey('product',related_name='product_review',null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  user=models.ForeignKey('UserProfile',related_name='user_review',null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  rating=models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1,null=True,blank=True,validators=[MaxValueValidator(5.0),MinValueValidator(0.0)])
  reviews=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

and this serializer

```
class productReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField(read_only='True')
    username = serializers.CharField(read_only='True')
    class Meta:
        model = product_review
        fields = ['product','username','rating','reviews']
```

So when i run this its just showing blank `{}` json but when i replace

`product_id__slug = productname`

with `rating = 4`
then its giving correct output

so i think there might some mistake in serializer can anyine please help me in that and tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: serializer = productReviewSerializer(snippets, **many=True**)

Comment: can u please explain the logic behind this.........why was it behaving differently on two same type of queries?

Comment: Take a look at the raw sql queries under the hood by printing them to console while running `manage.py runserver`.  See [this](http://gagor.pl/2014/05/quickly-setup-sql-query-logging-on-console-in-django/) to print the SQL statements to the console.